# Merge Like Items in ArrayList

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have an ArrayList the populates from onClick of a few Buttons. I'm trying to figure how to get my ArrayList to combine like items into one item. User pushes button once and "1 whatever" is populated in the list. If they push the same button again it will say "1 whatever" then "1 whatever" again in the list. How do I get my List to show "2 whatever" if the button is pushed twice?

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//Regular List
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);

//List From Another Activity
ArrayList<String> ai= new ArrayList<String>();
ai = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("list");
if (ai != null) {
listItems.add(ai+"");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//When the User pushes this button
//StackOverFlow help, Ignore this part if it's useless...wasnt sure
lay1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
listItems.add("1 "+stringm1a+" - "+intm1aa );
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
overallTotalproduct =  intm1aa + overallTotalproduct;
            textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalproduct));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Textwatcher..I bet. Just cant figure how.

Comment: The items are always of the format "item_count<space>item_name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend seperating the item count from the item name rather than storing both values in a String, and using your own custom Object adapter. It'll be a lot easier than working with Strings.

However, I think this should work:

```
String item = "1 Whatever";

// If the list contains this String
if (listItems.contains(item)) {
    String[] words = item.split(" ");        // Split the count and name
    int count = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);  // Parse the count into an int
    count++;                                 // Increment it
    listItems.remove(item);                  // Remove the original item
    listItems.add(count + " " + words[1]);   // Add the new count + name eg "2 Whatever"
}
```

The downside is this will not preserve your list order but you can always use `Collections.sort()` to sort it after any modifications.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have a ArrayList in which you add items of when few buttons are Clicked, if the same button is clicked twice or more you do not want to add item but increment the number of items present in list.

To address this , you can define an Item class which has class members String which you can use to 
identify the item and a count to track the number of Clicks

```
class Item
{
String str;
int count; 
}
```

Then on each Button ,define the String , before adding the elements to ArrayList,Search for the String if it already exists in the List, Increment the count if String is found